# Output MySQL source results to log file

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I am trying to execute foo.sql using the source command in MySQL.

When I type the command, the file is sourced accordingly:

```
mysql> source ~/foo.sql
```

Now, there are a lot of statements being executed in this file and I would like to review the success/failure of these statements.  Is there a way I can pipe the results of the statements to a log file, foo.txt?

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
mysql> source ~/foo.sql into outfile ~/foo.txt
```

However, typing this command appears to assume that everything following the source statement is one file name; so it is trying to source a file named '~/foo.sql into outfile ~/foo.txt', which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you checked the `pager` command?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From within your MySQL client, type

```
tee session.out
```

From that point on, all the I/O of in your current client session is written to the file 'session.out'

Comment: Also, if you want to stop the output, just type `notee` ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html))

Comment: I'd also jout like to highlight that you can use any text format for this e.g. `session.log` etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it from the shell prompt:

```
$ mysql -p dbname < foo.sql > foo.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command line:

```
mysql -p dbname < ~/foo.sql > ~/foo.txt
```

Comment: Did the database load as you wanted it to though?  Only error messages will be added to the file.  Oh, it will also stop on the first error, unless you give it a command line option to keep going past errors.

Comment: It completed without error at first.  I then tried it again and set my max_allowed_packet to 5M so it would intentionally error.  It did get an error but foo.txt did not list this error.